# Ubuntu 16.04 ethernet issue: cannot ping IP address

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am new to Ubuntu and recently lost internet connection - cannot connect to 8.8.8.8 or google.com. I open the network manager and it says I'm connected with the correct hardware address and IP Address fe80::1037:4526:e2b:d5c3 . However, this is not the IP address of my ethernet router. I am able to connect to this ethernet port via a Windows partition on the same computer. IPv4 is set to Automatic(DHCP) and IPv6 is set to Automatic. Here are the output of some relevant commands:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:90:96:a5:d7:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::1037:4526:e2b:d5c3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

$dmesg |grep eth0
[    1.603310] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 98:90:96:a5:d7:ae
[    1.603311] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.603348] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    1.603863] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0

$sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 05
       serial: 98:90:96:a5:d7:ae
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:28 memory:fb100000-fb11ffff memory:fb139000-fb139fff ioport:f020(size=32)

$ ifconfig -a
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:90:96:a5:d7:ae  
          inet6 addr: fe80::1037:4526:e2b:d5c3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1715192 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:154706 (154.7 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb100000-fb120000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:23808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1798264 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:1798264 (1.7 MB)

$ more /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

$ vi etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

$ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jan  7 06:46 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

$ dpkg -l *dns*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  dns-root-data  2018013001~1 all          DNS root data including root zone
un  dnscache-run   <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  dnsmasq        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  dnsmasq-base   2.75-1ubuntu amd64        Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/
ii  dnsutils       1:9.10.3.dfs amd64        Clients provided with BIND
un  fpdns          <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  isc-dhcp-clien <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  isc-dhcp-clien <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libapache2-mod <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  libdns-export1 1:9.10.3.dfs amd64        Exported DNS Shared Library
ii  libdns162:amd6 1:9.10.3.dfs amd64        DNS Shared Library used by BIND
ii  libnet-dns-per 0.81-2build1 amd64        Perform DNS queries from a Perl s
un  libnet-dns-sec <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnss-mdns:am 0.10-7       amd64        NSS module for Multicast DNS name
un  pdnsd          <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  rdnssd         <none>       <none>       (no description available)

$ dpkg -l *resolv*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  resolvconf     1.78ubuntu6  all          name server information handler

$ ls -al /boot
total 139844
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Jan 11 14:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root     4096 Jan 11 14:21 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1537161 Jul 18  2018 abi-4.15.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   216815 Jul 18  2018 config-4.15.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217026 Dec  7 11:05 config-4.15.0-43-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Jan 11 14:23 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 54459735 Jan  8 06:48 initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 61868943 Jan 11 14:24 initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Jul 18  2018 retpoline-4.15.0-29-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4039561 Jul 18  2018 System.map-4.15.0-29-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4047366 Dec  7 11:05 System.map-4.15.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8101496 Jul 30  2018 vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8119768 Dec  8 04:43 vmlinuz-4.15.0-43-generic

$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
#Domains=
#LLMNR=yes
#DNSSEC=no

$ dmesg |grep -i dhcp
[   12.059135] audit: type=1400 audit(1551975180.569:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=534 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.059137] audit: type=1400 audit(1551975180.569:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=534 comm="apparmor_parser"

$ dhclient -v enp0s25
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s25/98:90:96:a5:d7:ae
Sending on   LPF/enp0s25/98:90:96:a5:d7:ae
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s25 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xaa3dfb7d)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database – sleeping.
```

It seems odd that the route output is blank and also that the eth0 device is missing from interfaces. How can I get connected? Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90805/discussion-on-question-by-scott-sterrett-ubuntu-16-04-ethernet-issue-cannot-pin).

Comment: @terdon, I tried to do that but was blocked by the site because I/the user did not have enough experience. sorry!

Comment: Don't worry about it! That's an automatic comment that's inserted by the system when a moderator (me, in this case) moves comments to chat. It's a bit more brusque than necessary. It was not intended as a rebuke, but only to let you know that the conversation has been moved to chat and you can continue it there. Since the room was spawned by your question, you will be able to chat there normally. Please let me know if you can't!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a dhcp problem, you can try to run `dhclient -v enp0s25` to get an ipv4 adress.

You'll need to declare it in your /etc/network/interfaces or in your network manager to get it persistent

```bsh
auto enp0s25
allow-hotplug enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet dhcp
```

About the missing eth0, it's not a bug it's a feature, since 2 years, interfaces are assigned a weird name, you can undo this by adding 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0"` in `/etc/default/grub`

Finally, fe80::1037:4526:e2b:d5c3 address is a link-local ipv6 address, you cant use it to connect to internet but you can use it to connect to your LAN.

Wubalubadubdub

Comment: I added the output of that command to the original post. No dhcp offers were found. Should I still edit my interfaces? That sounds like an unreliable fix.

Comment: @ScottSterrett no, you shouldn't have to edit `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer...**

From the comments and chat...

After reviewing all of the network settings, I'm convinced that the problem is external to the Ubuntu software installation. Your ethernet interface looks like it's actually working. DHCP/IPv4/DNS seem broken. You're not getting a IPv4 address. Most recently we've booted to a Ubuntu Live 16.04 USB, and it also fails to connect to the Internet.

Recommended that the user log a trouble ticket with the College's IT department for resolution.

**Will monitor...**

Comment: This issue should be closed. The answer could not be provided by my IT department. However, I no longer needed a dual boot on the harddrive so I erased the entire disk and installed via the same usb iso and got a OS that is able to connect via ethernet.

Comment: @ScottSterrett I'm glad iti's working for you. I'm confused though, as we had Internet connectivity problems when booted to the Ubuntu Live USB... which thereby indicated that the problem was external to the box, and not with the original software installation. Go figure.